# Toolbar overlaps the PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

As you see in the title, The toolbar appears, but it overlaps my preferenceFragment content.
I fixed the issue on the Settings Screen by adding a padding to the listview.
But the problem persists in all the other preferenceFragments. Here is my code.

Activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ClassFragment()).commit();


        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_students, false);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_information, false);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_security, false);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_notifications, false);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,
                R.xml.pref_logout, false);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

       @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_addStudent:
                displayToast(getString(R.string.action_addStudent_message));
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this,
                        SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
                return true;
            default:
                // Do nothing
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


        public void displayToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private  BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_class:
                            selectedFragment = new ClassFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_due:
                            selectedFragment = new DueFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_messages:
                            selectedFragment = new MessagesFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_class_updates:
                            selectedFragment = new ClassUpdatesFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };


}
```

SettingsActivity

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.RingtonePreference;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.NavUtils;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.schooltest.Settings.AppCompatPreferenceActivity;

import java.util.List;


public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener
            sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener =
            new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
                    String stringValue = value.toString();

                    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                        // the preference's 'entries' list.
                        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                        int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                        // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                        preference.setSummary(
                                index >= 0
                                        ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                        : null);

                    } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                        // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
                        // using RingtoneManager.
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                            // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                            preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

                        } else {
                            Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                                    preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                            if (ringtone == null) {
                                // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                                preference.setSummary(null);
                            } else {
                                // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                                // name.
                                String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                                preference.setSummary(name);
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                        // simple string representation.
                        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };


    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }


    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);


        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
                .onPreferenceChange(preference, PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();

        int horizontalMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int verticalMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int topMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin) + 30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        getListView().setPadding(horizontalMargin, topMargin, horizontalMargin, verticalMargin);
    }


    private void setupActionBar() {
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, (ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }


    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || StudentsPreferenceFragment
                .class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || InformationPreferenceFragment
                .class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || SecurityPreferenceFragment
                .class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || NotificationsPreferenceFragment
                .class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || LogoutPreferenceFragment
                .class.getName().equals(fragmentName);

    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows student preferences only.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class StudentsPreferenceFragment
            extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_students);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows information preferences.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class InformationPreferenceFragment
            extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_information);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);


            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("first_name"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("last_name"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows security preferences.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class SecurityPreferenceFragment
            extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_security);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    /**
     * This fragment shows notifications preferences.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class NotificationsPreferenceFragment
            extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notifications);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);


            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(
                    findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows logout preferences.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class LogoutPreferenceFragment
            extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_logout);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you see in this photo, the "First Name" EditTextPreference is hidden by the toolbar:
[image]

I think, maybe it has something to do with the preference ressource files under xml/. so here a link to the files : https://github.com/waeljomni/apptest.git

Comment: Please post `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are inflating the `activity_main.xml` layout in `android.R.id.content` and the preference fragments into `com.android.internal.R.id.headers` (if you see the implementation of `PreferenceActivity`).

The default XML layout of `PreferenceActivity` is `preference_list_content`.
You should define in your team your custom preference layout in which you reproduce your main `Activity` layout.

See `headerLayout` in `R.attr.preferenceActivityStyle`.

Comment: I tried this solution, but unfortunately the problem persists. I added a link to the project. Can you take a look at the preference files under xml, please ?

Comment: @WaelJomni Oh I understood, the problem and it's way more complex, I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) so I shouldn't use headers.xml in the first place and create a customised preference_list_content layout instead ? 
I would also point out that the problem exist only in the preference fragment screens, but it works perfectly on the other screens

Comment: @WaelJomni 1. the problem exists only in the preference fragment screens because the `PreferenceActivity` has a different implementation from `MainActivity`. 2. Exactly, you should use a custom version `preference_list_content.xml` which will be used by your `PreferenceActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `ConstraintLayout` for performance reason and simplicity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">

</FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```